# Why does it not show when the next time I can ask a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderator, quality

Normally when I reach my question limit it tells me a date when I can ask again. Now it just says:

Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

When will this be lifted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

> How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
>
> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot
>   simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action,
>   you will never be allowed to post again. The only way for the ban to
>   be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.
>
> Moderators cannot lift the ban.
>
> Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! As noted above,
>   down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so
>   the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any
>   objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did
>   they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled,
>   formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!
>
> Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts. As explained
>   above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do
>   still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not
>   help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions you can
>   see a list of your own deleted questions and answers.
>
> If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality
>   answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But
>   as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for
>   sure.
>
> If you really, really think the ban is an error, then email the team
>   directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every
>   page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts is not a high
>   priority.